# Can't connect to a Windows share from Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba

I am trying to connect to a Windows share from my Ubuntu 14.10 machine.

- I can access the share fine from Windows.
- A colleague can access the share fine from his Arch machine.
- I have tried in Nautilus; it will ask for my username, domain and password, but whatever I type in, it just pops up the same authentication dialog again and again.
- I can ping the machine from my Linux machine.
- The following error message is from an `smbclient` build that has no `smb.conf`.
- The account I am trying to connect to is an Active Directory account.
- The machine I'm trying to connect to is on a Windows domain (I think; we have no Linux domains here that I'm aware of) but the machine I'm trying to connect from isn't.

If I try `smbclient`, I get:

```
$ smbclient -L //<the machine>/<the share> -U<username> -W <domain>
params.c:OpenConfFile() - Unable to open configuration file     "/home/amagee/amagee/etc/smb.conf":
        No such file or directory
./smbclient: Can't load /home/amagee/amagee/etc/smb.conf - run testparm to debug it
Enter <username>'s password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
```

Same if I try `smbclient -L //<the machine>/<the share> -U"<domain>\<username>"`.

This happens both with the `smbclient` available in the Ubuntu apt repositories (`Version 4.1.11-Ubuntu`) and one I just compiled from source (4.1.16).

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your `smb.conf` show? Are your machines on a domain? A Windows domain? A Linux (Samba) domain? How are your user accounts managed? Local accounts? Active Directory? PAM on Linux? We need more info about your setup

Comment: Edited with some extra details.